# Draw on picture box and print it

Tags: c#

Hi I want to make my picture box to be a circle-shaped
Then print it.

The problem is I can see in the form that the picture box is circle but when I'm previewing it to print it's not circle.

Here's my code

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        //This makes picturebox1 circle
        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath gp = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
        gp.AddEllipse(0, 0, pictureBox1.Width - 4, pictureBox1.Height - 4);
        Region rg = new Region(gp);
        pictureBox1.Region = rg;
    }


    //Preview the print
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printPrev.Document = printDoc;
        printPrev.ShowDialog();

    }

    private void printDoc_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {

        //Draw the picturebox on PDF
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, 230, 230);

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Your picture box is circle since you tell it to be. But when you print you print the image within, not the picture box. You have to have a clipping region set for that also.

Comment: Drawing a picturebox to paper is pretty unwise, you'll discover the effect of the big, big difference between the monitor and the printer resolution.  Every pixel on the screen turns into a 6x6 blob of ink, makes it look very grainy and only looks good when you have long arms.  But if you want to do this anyway then you have to use its DrawToBitmap() method.  The Graphics.Clip property also accepts a Region.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen how can i set the clipping region? can you give me some clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not working because you are not changing the Image.
You are only changing the graphics.
You could do something like this.

```
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
            g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black),3),0,0,bitmap.Width -4,bitmap.Height - 4);
            pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
```

This will also solve your problem

```
    using (var bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height)) {
                pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0,  bmp.Width,bmp.Height));
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 230, 230);
            }
```

Comment: It just draw a circle in paint but my picture disappears .

Comment: I tried the second code snippet but it doesnt work. It still print the original image not the circle one

Comment: I just add the second code snippet to the print method .

check out here
[link](http://pastebin.com/7tULeuPP)

Comment: Remove the using statement